# Search Code Only Searches One Row (When Working)

Tags: excel, vba, search

I have a report file that has 84 columns and 249,000+ rows. (The number of rows will be different every month.) I need to be able to search the entire report for 9 search terms and report  whether the search terms occur in each row. (i.e. if the first terms is found, write "Yes" in column A, second term write "Yes" in column B, etc.).

The search terms may appear individually in ANY of columns between AQ and CC (not the same column in each row); in column CD the search term may be in a series of comma-separated text.

```
Sub CodeSearch()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Dim i As Long 
    Dim foundRng As Range 
    Dim Lastrow As Long 

    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'set worksheets 
    With ThisWorkbook 
        Set wsSource = .Worksheets("TestData") 
    End With
    
    With wsSource
    
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
    
    Set foundRng = Range("AQ" & i & ":CD" & i).Find("Term1") 
    If foundRng = True Then
        Worksheets("TestData").Range("A" & i).Value = "Yes" 
    End If
    
    Set foundRng = Range("AQ" & i & ":CD" & i).Find("Term2") 
    If foundRng Is True Then 
        Worksheets("TestData").Range("B" & i).Value = "Yes" 
    End If
    
    Set foundRng = Range("AQ" & i & ":CD" & i).Find("Term3") 
    If foundRng Is True Then 
        Worksheets("TestData").Range("C" & i).Value = "Yes" 
    End If
    
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End With 
End Sub
```

(code shortened, but you get the gist)
I am using column J to count the rows because it cannot be empty.

The first time I tried, I didn't have the With / End With and I had "If foundRng Is Nothing Then" on each line. That resulted in "Yes" being entered in each column of row 2 only. Once I changed "Is Nothing" to "Is True", I got an "Object variable or With block not set". I added the With block and I still get that message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.Range("AQ" & i & ":CD" & i)` (note leading period)

Comment: Try `Lastrow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row`. If `TestData` is the active sheet, you code tries to get the last used row number from it. Col J only have a used cell J2 (might be the header row). That is, `LastRow` is 2.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
Sub CodeSearch()
    Dim Lastrow As Long, rw As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestData")
        Set rw = .Range("AQ2:CD2")  'start on this row
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).row
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While rw.row <= Lastrow    'loop over rows
        'match is faster than find....
        If Not IsError(Application.Match("Term1", rw, 0)) Then
            rw.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value = "Yes"
        End If
        If Not IsError(Application.Match("Term2", rw, 0)) Then
            rw.EntireRow.Columns("B").Value = "Yes"
        End If
        If Not IsError(Application.Match("Term3", rw, 0)) Then
            rw.EntireRow.Columns("C").Value = "Yes"
        End If
        
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You Are Amazing!! Thanks so much for the help.   It even finds the two search terms I was concerned about - Term6 and Term6A - correctly.